# trying to pick key and value in xslt in the following payload i am getting as empty responce as null

Tags: xslt

this is the xml paylode i am trying to strip by using xslt.

```
               <products>
                    <sequenceNum>123456</sequenceNum>
                    <ecostQuoteType>0</ecostQuoteType>
                    <specifications>
                        <key>SP_ACC_PROVIDER</key>
                        <code>VZB</code>
                        <value> Business - VZB</value>
                    </specifications>
                    <specifications>
                        <key>SP_ACC_TECH</key>
                        <code>TDM or DWDM</code>
                        <value>TDM or DWDM</value>
                    </specifications>
                    <specifications>
                        <key>SP_APP_PERF_LEVEL</key>
                        <code>Platinum</code>
                        <value>Platinum</value>
                    </specifications>
```

this is how i am writing the xslt for pick that key and value from the above xml.

```
      <optimazationspecs>
            <xsl:for-each select="./products/specifications">
                <xsl:for-each select="key" />
                <xsl:for-each select="value" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </optimazationspecs>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of empty xsl:for-each elements. So you're saying "for each key do nothing", and "for each value do nothing". So you shouldn't be surprised that the stylesheet essentially does nothing. But you don't say what output you actually want, other than that you are "trying to strip" the document (whatever that means), which makes it hard to correct your code.

Answer (score 0):

What output do you expect? Your for-each-Loops are empty as Michael mentioned. At least add `<xsl:apply-templates/>` to get the information you need.
Try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="products">
    <xsl:for-each select="specification">
        <xsl:for-each select="key">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="value">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

But as I said I don't know what sense this should make. And `<optimazationspecs>` is a XSLT compile error.